# How can i fix error when try to get data from API

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I tried to create web that display data from imdb api use jquery, but i got some problem with that.
the data display when i run on my localhost but when i deploy to netlify it didnt work, and in my console got error:
"Blocked loading mixed active content “http://omdbapi.com/?apikey=myapikey=moviename"

```js
function searchMovie() {
  $('#movie-list').html('');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://omdbapi.com',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      'apikey': 'dca61bcc',
      's': $('#search-input').val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
      if (result.Response == "True") {
        let movies = result.Search;

        $.each(movies, function(i, data) {
          $('#movie-list').append(`
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="card mb-3">
                                    <img src="${data.Poster}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">${data.Title}</h5>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${data.Year}</h6>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link see-detail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="${data.imdbID}">See Detail</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        `);
        });

        $('#search-input').val('');

      } else {
        $('#movie-list').html(`
                        <div class="col">
                            <h1 class="text-center">` + result.Error + `</h1>
                        </div>
                    `)
      }
    }
  });
}

$('#search-button').on('click', function() {
  searchMovie();
});

$('#search-input').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    searchMovie();
  }
});


$('#movie-list').on('click', '.see-detail', function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://omdbapi.com',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
      'apikey': 'dca61bcc',
      'i': $(this).data('id')
    },
    success: function(movie) {
      if (movie.Response === "True") {

        $('.modal-body').html(`
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <img src="` + movie.Poster + `" class="img-fluid">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><h3>` + movie.Title + `</h3></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">Released : ` + movie.Released + `</li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">Genre : ` + movie.Genre + `</li>                 
                                        <li class="list-group-item">Director : ` + movie.Director + `</li>                 
                                        <li class="list-group-item">Director : ` + movie.Actors + `</li>                 
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    `);

      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>WPU Movie</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WPU Movie</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Search Movie</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row mt-3 justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1 class="text-center">Search Movie</h1>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Movie title.." id="search-input">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button" id="search-button">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="row" id="movie-list">

    </div>


  </div>



  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Movie Search</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>







  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_

Comment: Blocked loading mixed active content `http://omdbapi.com/?apikey=myapikey=moviename`?
you need to use `https` protocol.